# Can someone explain what is happening behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, .net, events

It's not entirely obvious to me what's happening in this situation.

I'd expect both functions to be fired.

Either the EventHander class is storing the list of functions to fire as an array - and the array is copied to a new one every time something is added/removed - or when the assignment is made, the whole thing is copied to a new "collection" - and not just a reference.

Somebody please enlighten me :D

Here's a little Linqpad script:

```
public class Moop
{
    public EventHandler myEvent;
}

void Main()
{
    var moo = new Moop();
    moo.myEvent += (o, sender) => { "Added to Moop #1".Dump(); };   

    var moo2 = new Moop();

    //Copy the reference, I assume?
    moo2.myEvent = moo.myEvent;

    moo2.myEvent += (o, sender) => { "Added to Moop #2".Dump(); }; 

    //Fire the event on #1
    moo.myEvent(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Behold the power of operator overloading and the evils it brings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Event handler lists are delegates, and delegates are immutable -- like strings. So you do copy the delegate, and the second event handler gets "added to" the 2nd delegate, not the first.

You can find out more about delegates at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/delegates-in-C-Sharp/

Good luck!

Comment: More precisely, the second `Moop`'s delegate instance is replaced by the union of the original value ("Added to Moop #1"...) and the second event handler ("Added to Moop #2"...).  So when you do `+= ...` you are replacing the value on the left hand side.  But the gist of this answer is correct.

Comment: Indeed. That is why I placed the "added to" between quotes.

Comment: To make it a bit clearer (not contradicting anything you said), `delegate += newDelegate;` roughly means `delegate = Delegate.Combine(delegate, newDelegate);`, and from that it is a lot clearer that a new delegate is assigned to the field.